# PHP generate random directory for fileupload

Tags: php

I need to generate random directories for user file uploads.
Is it wise to use the following function for this?

```
hash('md5', time())
```

I don't want PHP to tamper with the filenames, that's why I thought about using directories for this.

Comment: What about collisions?

Comment: md5 the file name and use first three letters for a path for folder...

Comment: I don't think hash collisions would be very likely in this instance, but I would use `microtime(true)` instead of `time` to avoid collisions when two uploads happen in the same second. Maybe even append `rand()` to the end of the hash?

Comment: Or, even better, use an auto-incrementing number as the folder. If your app doesn't use a database yet, you could put the number in a file and add one to it after each use. I'll put this option in an answer

Comment: you can use ```uniqid()```

Comment: Ok, yeah, @ShawnVn 's solution is better than mine. You can even go crazy with it adding a prefix and additional entropy: `uniqid( substr( $filename, 0, 3 ), true );`

Comment: If this is for user uploads why not hash a unique user element such as the email or userid? That way you won't have to worry about concurrency issues, just database integrity issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use auto-increment to be sure you never get the same directory name twice:

```
$i = file_get_contents('increment.txt');
file_put_contents( $i + 1, 'increment.txt' );

// Then use $i as the directory name

// Or if you want the dirname to be less easily guessed:
$dirname = md5(microtime(true) . $filename) . $i;
```

Comment: This should even work without manually creating `increment.txt`, because if the file doesn't exist, file_get_contents will return false, and `false + 1` is 1!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a time based approach, as you are doing, but it is more wise to use microtime instead of time because the entropy is larger and thus the chance of collision is smaller.

An even better approach is to generate a really unique ID. You could use the build-in uniqid function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) with the extra entropy option, or the excelent ramsey/uuid library (https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) that generates a strong unique identifier based on the RFC 4122 standard. The chance of collisions here is so small it is practically non-existent (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions).

You could use an increment-approach, where you store/retrieve the amount of directories that already exist, but that will mean you have an extra load on your file system and you miss the possibility to make multiple directories asynchronously.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How many users and files you are going to process?
Remember about an effect of many files/folders living in the same folder: if you have few hundreds or thousands files in the same directory, working with that directory becomes slow. 
My advice: split the generated hash into few parts and create directory structure like this:
/uploads/user/f4/a9/f4a94637deabc55/file.jpg

Answer (score 0):

for php 7.0+

```
while (true) {
 $dirName = uniqid(random_int(100, 999), true);
 if (!file_exists(sys_get_temp_dir() . $dirName)) break;
}
echo $dirName . ' - is unique dir, to write in!';
```